# In FTP command mode, how do I redirect command line and the result when using shell script using here document to let ftp command read stdin

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ftp

I am trying to write shell script that implements FTP command reading here documents.

How do I redirect ftp command line AND results FTP server returns?

My current script is below

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp -ivn <<EOF |& tee ftplog.text
open <myFtpserver>
user <username> <password>
pwd
ls -l MYFILE_*
bye
EOF
```

This code outputs ftp server's response but ftp command to ftplog.txt.
How can I redirect both?

I appreciate your help

Comment: Replace `|& tee` with `>`?

Comment: added `debug` in the here document and it displayed my command lines.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your script on this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp -ivn >ftplog.text  <<EOF 
open <myFtpserver>
user <username> <password>
pwd
ls -l MYFILE_*
bye
EOF
```

The redirection is to the command, not inline block